Trying to create a Youtube to MP3 downloader via norkunas/youtube-dl-php; but I'm getting an empty array when it should be an audio file. See code:
I'm basically following their docs: https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php
and I have yt-dlp installed as well.
$url is a valid Youtube URL.
$format is .mp3.
Here's my code:

    public function download()
    {
        $url = $this->request->getPost('url'); // Retrieve URL from the form
        $format = $this->request->getPost('format') ?? 'mp3';

        if (empty($url)) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Please provide a YouTube URL.');
        }

        /*
         *   BEGIN
         */
        $outputDir = WRITEPATH . 'downloads/';
        // Ensure output directory exists
        if (!is_dir($outputDir)) {
            mkdir($outputDir, 0755, true);
        }
        // START
        $yt = new YoutubeDl();
        $yt->setBinPath('/home/master/.local/bin/yt-dlp');

        try {
            $collection = $yt->download(
                Options::create()
                    ->downloadPath($outputDir)
                    ->extractAudio(true)
                    ->audioFormat($format)
                    ->audioQuality('0') // best
                    ->output('%(title)s.%(ext)s')
                    ->url($url)
            );
        
            if ($collection->count() === 0) {
                echo "No videos found for the provided URL.";
            } else {
                foreach ($collection->getVideos() as $video) {
                    if ($video->getError() !== null) {
                        echo "Error downloading video: {$video->getError()}.";
                    } else {
                        echo "Success! Video: {$video->getTitle()} has been downloaded.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

that whole thing echos out:
No videos found for the provided URL.
and when var_dump (iirc) $collection: object(YoutubeDl\Entity\VideoCollection)#97 (1) { ["elements":protected]=> array(0) { } }

Not every video is public or available without beeing authentificated to pass age verification.
